Slow execution while Filtering and Selecting Columns in Dask DataFrame Using query() and compute()
I'm working with a large Dask DataFrame (data) and I need to filter rows based on a specific ID (id12) in the column named 'ID'. Additionally, I want to select only two columns ('col1' and 'col2') from the filtered DataFrame. Here's the approach I'm currently using:
data_filtered = data.query(f"ID == 'id12' ")[['col1','col2']].reset_index(drop=True).compute() 
Where:
data is my Dask DataFrame.
'ID' is the column containing IDs.
'id12' is the specific ID I'm filtering for.
'col1' and 'col2' are the columns I want to select after filtering.
I'm using query() to filter rows based on the ID and then selecting specific columns using indexing ([['col1', 'col2']]). Finally, I call compute() to retrieve the actual data into memory.
Issue:
Performance Concerns: This approach seems to work, but I'm concerned about its efficiency, it is taking good time around 30sec to execute.
Any insights or alternative approaches to optimize performance and memory usage would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Could you give more context about the data you are reading? Which volume? Format? Why are you concerned with performances?

Hi @GuillaumeEB. Data is having around 420k rows and format is dask dataframe. I am running this in loop by selecting one id at a time I have around 35k unique ID's for each iteration it is taking 30sec that where like I wanted to reduce this time

What is the input format? Why are you not using Pandas?
